# Windows Shuts down, Computer won't turn off

Tags: windows-7, ssd, shutdown

Upgraded a Gateway (ugh) desktop to an SSD. Now whenever I shut down Windows the machine stays on. Windows shuts down cleanly, but the computer won't turn off: the fans and power light stay on. If I swap back to the HDD it turns off correctly.

I've updated all the drivers I can and still the same. I updated to the latest BIOS. Any other ideas?

Windows 7 Home
Gateway tower
Core i5
Crucial MX300 SSD

Comment: how are you shutting the machine down?

Comment: Start > Shut down

Comment: Hibernate is off, bios updated, SSD firmware updated.

Comment: Is the SSD the first boot device in BIOS, and is the old HDD still in the machine with the old installation intact?

Answer (score 1):

1. Reset BIOS to clear CMOS.
2. Update motherboard driver from manufacturer's official website.
3. Unplug, remove battery. Put battery back.
4. Perform a clean boot to check. [How to perform a clean boot in Windows | support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows)
5. Reset your Power Setting to one of the default settings, e.g. "balanced and rebooting the PC.
6. Select Command Prompt (Admin) and click ‘Yes’ to the uac prompt.
   Type ( or copy and paste ) in the following command ( including spaces ) and hit enter.

   shutdown /s /t 0

Comment: Did all those, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different SATA slot than your DVD drive used (the one you installed Windows from).

I know it sounds ridiculous but it worked for me

(if you dont have an option to do that (laptop), you will need to reinstall windows from USB or buy an USB caddy for a SSD drive. )

Comment: A different SATA jack is interesting. Machine is gone; user decided to fix the issue by replacing their old machine. HOwever, I have another device with the same issue, but it's the Lenovo all-in-one portable tablet/computer thing (cannot recall the name of it and I think they only had it one generation. It's like the Horizon, but smaller). I may tear it apart to see if it has a second SATA jack in there.It starts in a matter of a few seconds, but it won't even sleep correctly. Guess this is "answered" and I'll try another jack next time I have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because the SSD was in GPT mode.

Switched it to MBR and installed the NON-efi version of windows from USB. Problem solved!